# MYSQL query on DateTime, find existing bookings

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table which holds bookings for car parking spaces. the minimum booking time is 30 minutes and the maximum a booking can span is 1 full day (i.e a booking never goes across multiple days). Bookings must not overlap,i.e only 1 car per space at any one time, so I check first to see if a booking is available before inserting the new booking.

```
id      buyerid         startdatetime   enddatetime            vehicle  spaceid
2       5       2014-04-23 09:00:00     2014-04-23 21:30:00     2       1
3       6       2014-04-25 13:00:00     2014-04-25 22:00:00     3       1
```

I want to query the table, supplying a startdatetime, enddatetime and a spaceid and find out if a booking exists for that space at that given time. I just need to return true or false from the query.

For example with the current dataset you see above if i supplied:

`startdatetime=2014-04-23 09:00:00 AND enddatetime= 2014-04-23 11:00:00` -- the query would return TRUE because row id 2 defines a booking that exists at the supplied time.

`startdatetime=2014-04-23 22:00:00 AND enddatetime= 2014-04-23 23:30:00` -- the query would return FALSE because there is no booking at that time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what you want with a simple comparison and aggregation:

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 'false' else 'true' end)
from bookings b
where b.spaceid = @SPACEID and
      b.startdatetime < @ENDTIME and
      b.enddatetime > @STARTTIME;
```

Two periods overlap if one starts before the other ends, and ends after other starts.

Ideally, though, you would want to set up the table so no spaces can ever be booked at the same time.  One way to do this would be to have a table for each space and 48 slots for the day (one for each half hour).  Instead of a range on each row, you would have a row for each time slot.  Then you can have a unique constraint (index) on `spaceid, timeslot` and the database will enforce this logic for you -- with much less overhead than having to search through the table for potentially overlapping reservations.

Comment: that sounds just like what i need,however im struggling :s see spaces can also have subscriptions, ive come so far but its still so far away. I actually thought that creating a table for each space would be bad practice but seems not

Comment: @brux . . . Your question mentions nothing about subscriptions.  If you have a much enhanced problem, I would encourage you to ask *another* question.  It is unfair to edit this one, invalidating answers to the original question.

Comment: i mean that changing the definition of the db a per your suggestion for improvment would have further consequences, your answer is great and 100% correct after testing it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the simple SQL Statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE startdatetime > $Start
AND enddatetime < $End
```

And then put it into into `IF(expression ,expr_true, expr_false);` [see Doc here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

```
IF((SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE startdatetime > $Start
    AND enddatetime < $End
)  ,'true', 'false');
```